# How to pass number and string in codeigniter controller function via routing?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass a dynamic value in the URL. When hitting this URL with parameter pass this parameter one routing and call the function with this parameter. 
I would like:

route.php

```
$route['emp/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'ramelexController/employeeAttendance/$1/$a';
```

Controller.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    class ramelexController extends CI_Controller
    {
       public function employeeAttendance($id,$char)
       {
         echo $id.$char;
       }
    }
```

Comment: What error you got in that? Explain proper so others can answer you.

Comment: Your controller class and filename should be named `Ramelexcontroller` where only first letter upper case

Answer (score 4):

Slightly modify your routes.php:

```
$route['emp/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'ramelexController/employeeAttendance/$1/$2';
```

*Edited*: as mentioned in several comments, be aware of class naming: Controller and Class name needs to be first letter uppercase. `RamelexController` in your case.

Comment: The above answer works. Just note that under CI 3.x.x on Linux your Controller and Class name needs to be first letter uppercase. So in this instance your controller will be RamelexController.php and the class name will be RamelexController